# ViewPager with right/left scroll

Tags: android, android-viewpager

could somebody help me and give a example of how can I do a viewpager that can be rotated right/left, something like this: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-0Sjg8-LaZuo/TkxHAPOkAkI/AAAAAAAACgM/VjNo-nK9fuk/s1600/device-2011-08-18-005327.png

thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is this http://viewpagerindicator.com/ 
Best solution I have seen so far. 
Archive that you'll find on this site contains both library and example showing how to implement such type of GUI in you app.